# How to manipulate the gradient mesh correctly?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pen-tool, gradient-mesh

i am learning about illustrator technniques and i want to do this tutorial:

**design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-draw-a-vector-t-shirt-and-apply-a-pattern-to-it-in-adobe-illustrator--cms-28926** (sorry for don't put this like a link, this don't leave me to add more of 2 links)

Basically, i use the mesh to create something like this:

[image: Using the mesh tool]

The problem is that i cannot do the mesh like the example of the tutorial.
I start drawing the shape with the pen tool. Then i use the mesh tool to create the lines, but the lines is not even close that the sample was. See my example:

[image: My sample]

So, i try to do the shirt starting with a rectangle. This don't work neither.

What i should to do? I need to move the points until see like the sample? There Is another way to use or manipulate the mesh tool points and i can get the mesh like the tutorial? Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator will occasionally throw in `Helper` points on a mesh. These helper points are **not** immediately visible on the mesh. Their presence is often indicated by a sharp corner or direction change in a mesh path which doesn't seem to adhere to the bezier handles and points you *can* see.

Your image would seem to have a couple of these `helper` points.

[image]

To **remove** the `Helper` points, switch to the **Subtract Anchor Tool** (Just tap the - [minus] key on the keyboard).

As soon as you switch tools, you will then actually *see* the helper points, and can subsequently click them with the Subtract Anchor Tool to remove them. Adobe states the Helper points are smaller than actual mesh points -- that may be true, but to my eyes they aren't really much smaller.

[image]

When building a mesh on a complex shape, you often need to switch back and forth to the Subtract Anchor tool to kill the auto-generated `Helper` points. Basically, every time you add a new mesh path you need to check for `helpers`.

And it's also helpful to realize that you can place smaller meshes on top of solid shapes to create dimension. You do not ever need to build 1 mesh for 1 object.

Also be aware, you can **slide** a mesh point along it's path by holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and then click-dragging the point with the Mesh Tool. (You can't slide or edit Helper points. You can only move or remove them)

Ultimately trying to build 2 meshes which are identical, on 2 different systems, may a lesson in frustration unless you start with the *exact* same shape containing the *exact* same number of anchors in the *exact* same positions. And then you know *exactly* which order the mesh points where added and click in the *exact* same position. Meshes are a bit more forgiving than that. As long as you get relatively close, you should be able to create the appearance you want.